# Convert dataframe columns to named number vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `blah`:

```
blah <- data.frame(x=c("Red", "Blood Red", "Crimson", "Maroon"), y=c(20, 1, 14, 13))
```

I want to convert `blah` into a named number/member vector:

```
blah <- c(`Red` = 20, `Blood Red` = 1, `Crimson` = 14, `Maroon` = 13)
```

Where `x` is the name and `y` is the value.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Use case: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `setNames`

```
setNames(blah$y, blah$x)
# Red Blood Red   Crimson    Maroon 
#  20         1        14        13
```

Comment: R is the best. Will accept in 9 minutes. Thanks!